# Retrieving Power BI Usage Metrics via O365 API

Tags: powerbi

I'm making use of streaming datasets using O365 Management API, following the article: https://www.proserveit.com/blog/power-bi-usage-metrics-across-all-workspaces

it begins to push data up until a point where I get a "request is being blocked by the upstream service" error, see attached.

[image]

Is there a way I can bypass the throttling threshold that I seem to reach?